# NoReverseMatch at /animal_types/10/

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-urls

I get an error `NoReverseMatch at /animal_types/10/`

The exception value is: `Reverse for 'animal' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['animal\\/(?P<animal_id>[0-9]+)\\/$']`

Here is my views code for animal:

```
@login_required
def animal(request, animal_id):
    """shows a single animal and the schedule associated"""
    animal = Animal.objects.get(id=animal_id)
    schedule = animal.schedule_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'animal':animal, 'schedule':schedule}
    return render(request, 'zoo_animal_feeders/animal.html', context)
```

Any help is appreciated. Let me know if I need to include more information.

Here are my main urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('', include('zoo_animal_feeders.urls')),
]
```

Here is the app specific url that its trying to execute:

```
app_name = 'zoo_animal_feeders'
urlpatterns = [
    #This is for the home page
    path('', views.index, name='index'),

    #Show animal types
    path('animal_types/', views.animal_types, name='animal_types'),

    #Page that will access a certain category of animals
    path('animal_types/<int:animal_type_id>/', views.animal_type, name='animal_type'),

    #Page for accessing an animal (and its schedule)
    path('animal/<int:animal_id>/', views.animal, name='animal'),

    #Page for adding a new animal type
    path('new_animal_type/', views.new_animal_type, name='new_animal_type'),

    #Page for adding a new animal
    path('new_animal/<int:animal_type_id>/', views.new_animal, name='new_animal'),

    #page for adding a new schedule
    path('new_schedule/<int:animal_id>/', views.new_schedule, name='new_schedule'),

    #page for editing an animal
    path('edit_animal/<int:animal_id>/', views.edit_animal, name='edit_animal'),

    #page for editing a schedule
    path('edit_schedule/<int:schedule_id>/', views.edit_schedule, name='edit_schedule'),
```

]

Template for /animal_types/:

```
{% extends 'zoo_animal_feeders/base.html' %}

{% block header %}
  <h2>{{ animal_type }}</h2>
{% endblock header %}


{% block content %}
  <p><a href="{% url 'zoo_animal_feeders:new_animal' animal_type.id %}">add new animal</a></p>

  {% for animal in animals %}
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3>
          {{ animal.name }}
          <small>
            <a href="{% url 'zoo_animal_feeders:animal' schedule.id %}">see schedule</a>
            <a href="{% url 'zoo_animal_feeders:edit_animal' animal.id %}">edit animal</a>
          </small>
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        {{ animal.text|linebreaks }}
      </div>
    </div>
  {% empty %}
    <li>There are no animals for this animal type yet.</li>
  {% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

It won't allow me to put in the traceback because it is too much code (its a very long traceback).

Comment: You have defined `animal/...` but not `animal_types/...`.

Comment: I had `animal_types/` defined, I just posted all of my urls to confirm.

Comment: Please show your template

Comment: added template for /animal_types/

Answer (score 0):

The problem was this, `<a href="{% url 'zoo_animal_feeders:animal' schedule.id %}">see schedule</a>` I was pointing it to `schedule.id` and it needed to point to `animal.id`

This is the correct code:

```
<a href="{% url 'zoo_animal_feeders:animal' animal.id %}">see schedule</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specific variable name 'animal_id' in the url:

```
<a href="{% url 'zoo_animal_feeders:animal' animal_id=schedule.id %}">see schedule</a>
<a href="{% url 'zoo_animal_feeders:edit_animal' animal_id=animal.id %}">edit animal</a>
```

Good luck.